# When querying MongoDB should we use Query or Query<T>?

Tags: c#, mongodb

I'm looking at ways to make our mongo queries faster and more efficient.

We already get the collections by using `GetCollection<T>("CollectionName")`.

However, should we be building the queries by using `Query.EQ("fieldname", "fielddata")` or `Query<t>.EQ(x => x.FieldName, "fielddata")`? I personally prefer the second way but is it more efficient?

Is there any difference? Which should we be using?

Assuming they are running on the same hardware, querying the same databases.

Comment: Related reading: [Which is faster? by Eric Lippert](http://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/)

Comment: Not really helpful. It used to be that you'd write queries in stored procedures rather than inline queries in SQL Server because it was compiled and would run faster. I want to know if the same is true here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no difference between them
Mongo Engine act same to `Query<t>.EQ(x => x.FieldName, "fielddata")` and `Query.EQ("fieldname", "fielddata")` and finally both will be converted to Bson Document as `{ 'FieldName', 'fielddata'}`

Answer (score 2):

Well...

Query.EQ(x => x.FieldName, "fieldData") and Query.EQ("fieldName", "fieldData") will both result in the same json - { "fieldName": "fieldData" } assuming that you have mapped the T.FieldName property to camelCase "fieldName".

Given that, of course not using generics is going to result in a faster experience. It has to do less work. Using the typed form means we need to find the mapping information and apply it.

But the speed increase here is largely going to be unnoticeable unless you are doing millions of these things a second, which will likely be eclipsed by the network and mongo satisfying the query server side. Best thing to do is measure it.

Ultimately, the reason the generic forms exist is so you don't have to have your mapping information everywhere.